# Python can't assign object variable

Tags: python, oop

I try to assign variables through function when I create a class instance, but it doesn't work.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, l):
        self.l = l
        self.func(self.l) # or I tried self.func(l)
        self.z = None
        self.y = None

    def func(self, l):
        self.z = l  # doesn't work
        self.y = 123 # doesn't work

x = Test('test')
print(x.z) # = None
print(x.y) # = None
```

Can somebody explain this things, links are welcome to!

Comment: Can you make sure that the indentation is exactly the one of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redefining `self.z` and `self.y` as `None` after you define them with `func`. Get rid of the `self.z` and `self.y` in `__init__`

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self, l):
        self.l = l
        self.func(self.l) # or I tried self.func(l)
        # These are redefining the variables, comment out
        # self.z = None
        # self.y = None

    def func(self, l):
        self.z = l  
        self.y = 123
```

Comment: yeap, it definitely works! btw, I just set self.func call to the end of __init__. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For this you want to just make your `func(self)` no need to pass, since our function can call `self.l` from `__init__` , also `self.func(self.l)` is unnecessary, we can then use `func` by simply calling `x.func` and then it will change the values of `x.x` and `x.y`

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self, l):
        self.l = l
        self.z = None
        self.y = None

    def func(self):
        self.z = self.l  
        self.y = 123 

x = Test('test')
x.func()
print(x.z) # test
print(x.y) # 1 2 3
```

Answer (score -1):

Python is tab/space indent dependent this should work.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, l):
        self.l = l
        self.func(self.l)  # or I tried self.func(l)
        self.z = None
        self.y = None

    def func(self, l):
        self.z = l  # doesn't work
        self.y = 123  # doesn't work


x = Test('test')
print(x.z)  # = None
print(x.y)  # = None
```

Comment: Not quite. An indentation issue would raise a `SyntaxError` for an unexpected indent